# Move window from other (inactive) desktop to current desktop

Tags: xfce, xdotool

When using this to fetch window from another desktop to current desktop (which is #0), nothing happens until I focus the desktop with that window - then window immediately moves to the desktop 0.

`xdotool search --name "App Name" set_desktop_for_window 0`

How can be that window fetched without me focusing the other desktop?

DE: Xfce 4.16, WM: Xfwm4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wmctrl -R "App Name"` works great.